# In Laravel this Remote API connection doesn't work but the Curl works and Postman works

Tags: laravel

I'm trying this Remote API connection route and it doesn't work in Laravel:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

Route::get('sellers', function () {



    $response = http::get('url/api',[

       'debug' => true,
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization'     => 'Basic {Base64 Code Here}',
            'Accept'            => '{application/..text}'
        ]
    ]);

    dd($response->json());
});
```

And in Postman with a GET request and the same URL and the same header keys, it works:

```
Key                      Value 
Authorization           Basic {Base64 Code Here}
Accept                   {application/..text}
```

What's going on?

Comment: What is the description of the error ? Can you post its screenshot ?

Comment: Sorry, not at home right now but the error is the 406 Not Acceptable. I will post the screensho as soon as I get home.

Comment: You have to pass headers in withHeader method rather that get method. Refer to this : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-client . Let me know if it works out for you.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. It did work, you saved my day.

Comment: Glad it worked for you :)

Comment: I was killing myself, I had spent like 5 hours pulling my hair. I found many many blogs saying the my implementation was right, but never saw any mention to withHeader and still don't understand why Laravel would make it that difficult or safer I guess.